# Writing vectorised code for the following loop

Tags: softmax, numpy-indexing

This is the loop we have to vectorise:

```
for i in range(num_train):
  dW[y[i]] -= X[i]
```

The dimensions of the vectors are the following:

```
y - num_train,1
X - num_train,3073
dW - 10,3073
```

I have used the following advanced indexing method that seems to work correctly on the Python interpreter with small examples:

```
dW[y,] -= X[range(num_train),]
```

But this evaluates the loop incorrectly.

Comment: Can you please specify a current and an expected result?

Comment: for the cifar-10 dataset using the second methord results in a gradient value of 303 more than the expected result